# xcode-select error during pyobjc-core installation

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pyobjc

I am trying to install pyobjc-core which is a requirement for pyautogui. I am getting the below error while installing.  I have already updated setuptools using

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

and also using

```
sudo python3 ez_setup.py
```

I am on OSX Yosemite and using Python 3.5.

I see that the code below has a requirement for xcode. Could that be the reason and why would xcode be needed for this installation?

```
pip3 install pyobjc-core
Collecting pyobjc-core
  Using cached pyobjc-core-3.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info
    writing include/pyobjc-compat.h to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/include/pyobjc-compat.h
    writing include/pyobjc-api.h to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/include/pyobjc-api.h
    writing namespace_packages to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/private/var/folders/zw/573csqzn0pnbjkb44gw2s7800000gn/T/pip-build-72bxsxfe/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 696, in 
        **parse_package_metadata()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/zw/573csqzn0pnbjkb44gw2s7800000gn/T/pip-build-72bxsxfe/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 371, in run
        egg_info.egg_info.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 193, in run
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 216, in find_sources
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 300, in run
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 329, in add_defaults
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 132, in add_defaults
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/zw/573csqzn0pnbjkb44gw2s7800000gn/T/pip-build-72bxsxfe/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 525, in finalize_options
        universal_newlines=True).strip()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 711, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-version', '-sdk', 'macosx', 'Path']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zw/573csqzn0pnbjkb44gw2s7800000gn/T/pip-build-72bxsxfe/pyobjc-core/
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear: you need xcode...

It's silly but unfortunately there are these **developer tools** that are tied to it, and since many packages require dev tools (in your specific case `xcodebuild` needs it) you have to install xcode (anyway it's free)